# Iphone/IOS - Debugging Application Crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, sandbox

From what I've read, this topic has come up several times over the last few years and usually with very vague answers, plus there hasn't been a mention of it from what I've found in over a year so I'm hoping there's been progress.

Anyway, I currently have an Iphone 4 with IOS 5.0.1 installed, and am having the issue where most applications installed from the App Store are crashing on splash screen. There are many people who say installing a random application from the App Store, reinstalling the app, or restoring your phone completely will fix this problem, but it doesn't seem to have the same effect anymore (as most of these suggestions were for IOS 4 and 3, not 5).

So, what I've done is just trying to find the source of the issues. I'll be using the popular and well known app UrbanSpoon as my example for the crashes. Below are the syslog and crash report after attempting to run UrbanSpoon. From what I can understand from them, it has something to do with how IOS sandboxes applications, but I can't figure out which part specifically says what could be causing the crash.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, hoping these answers will benefit everyone having this issues!

**SysLog:**

(Snipped from log file from when UrbanSpoon was first executed to the last mention of the application)

EDIT:
Syslog is too big to post here, here's a link to it instead.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9235267/MyiPhoneSysLogForUrbanSpoon.txt

**Crash Report for UrbanSpoon:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AutoSubmitted</key>
    <true/>
    <key>SysInfoCrashReporterKey</key>
    <string>38f6d9c3d504f902f8dbae968517559766e3092d</string>
    <key>bug_type</key>
    <string>109</string>
    <key>description</key>
    <string>Incident Identifier: 568DB2CE-F9A2-47A7-A427-B5C4DF6A09D0
CrashReporter Key:   38f6d9c3d504f902f8dbae968517559766e3092d
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         urbanspin [282]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/42579EAA-3CD0-4B2B-BFF5-5EB1C9297207/urbanspin.app/urbanspin
Identifier:      urbanspin
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-01-04 13:22:22.479 -0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.urbanspoon.urbanspin failed to launch in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 20.580 (user 20.580, system 0.000), 100% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.511, 2% CPU

Thread 0:
0   ???                             0x34a7f110 0 + 883421456
1   Foundation                      0x32356c92 0x32350000 + 27794
2   AnyRingLib.dylib                0x00379a3e 0x377000 + 10814
3   dyld                            0x2febdf80 0x2feb1000 + 53120
4   dyld                            0x2febdbcc 0x2feb1000 + 52172
5   dyld                            0x2febb7d0 0x2feb1000 + 42960
6   dyld                            0x2febc790 0x2feb1000 + 46992
7   dyld                            0x2feb35c0 0x2feb1000 + 9664
8   dyld                            0x2feb9106 0x2feb1000 + 33030
9   ???                             0x3367b5a4 0 + 862434724
10  SubstrateLoader.dylib           0x000d46ae 0xd3000 + 5806
11  SubstrateLoader.dylib           0x000d4828 0xd3000 + 6184
12  dyld                            0x2febdece 0x2feb1000 + 52942
13  dyld                            0x2febdbd4 0x2feb1000 + 52180
14  dyld                            0x2febb7d0 0x2feb1000 + 42960
15  dyld                            0x2febc790 0x2feb1000 + 46992
16  dyld                            0x2feb35c0 0x2feb1000 + 9664
17  dyld                            0x2feb9106 0x2feb1000 + 33030
18  ???                             0x3367b5a4 0 + 862434724
19  MobileSubstrate.dylib           0x0009aea0 0x9a000 + 3744
20  dyld                            0x2febdece 0x2feb1000 + 52942
21  dyld                            0x2febdbd4 0x2feb1000 + 52180
22  dyld                            0x2febb7d0 0x2feb1000 + 42960
23  dyld                            0x2febc790 0x2feb1000 + 46992
24  dyld                            0x2feb39f0 0x2feb1000 + 10736
25  dyld                            0x2feb7b80 0x2feb1000 + 27520
26  dyld                            0x2feb22ca 0x2feb1000 + 4810
27  dyld                            0x2feb205c 0x2feb1000 + 4188

Thread 1:
0   ???                             0x34a7e3b4 0 + 883418036
1   ???                             0x34beab98 0 + 884911000
2   ???                             0xfffffffc 0 + -4

Thread 2:
0   ???                             0x34a8ecd4 0 + 883485908
1   ???                             0x3626d0a0 0 + 908513440

Thread 3:
0   ???                             0x34a8ecd4 0 + 883485908
1   ???                             0x3626d0a0 0 + 908513440

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x74fff +urbanspin armv7  &lt;0b3e8cdf11113d1abf4c0d83ef1a3ebe&gt; /var/mobile/Applications/42579EAA-3CD0-4B2B-BFF5-5EB1C9297207/urbanspin.app/urbanspin
   0x9a000 -    0x9afff +MobileSubstrate.dylib armv6  &lt;cf2cce379dcd3a4c970e3196b908b0b6&gt; /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib
   0xd3000 -    0xd4fff +SubstrateLoader.dylib armv6  &lt;30381ec9e24c3c289f447bf428bda2c1&gt; /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib
   0xf7000 -    0xfafff  libsubstrate.dylib armv6  &lt;d375337d03a7324c9cfb608b7231eeea&gt; /usr/lib/libsubstrate.dylib
  0x300000 -   0x311fff +ActionMenu.dylib armv6  &lt;62581e9bc0d93ef2ab8175cd5e337e62&gt; /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ActionMenu.dylib
  0x318000 -   0x321fff +Activator.dylib armv6  &lt;53595f5e871d3d7eac4f8e945b039de3&gt; /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
  0x329000 -   0x365fff +AdBlocker.dylib armv6  &lt;07089bfdb5563a33bee5fc772477dd33&gt; /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/AdBlocker.dylib
  0x377000 -   0x396fff +AnyRingLib.dylib armv6  &lt;98857b11e0d73e13dfb59d83ed186a0e&gt; /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/AnyRingLib.dylib
0x2feb1000 - 0x2fed2fff  dyld armv7  &lt;be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06&gt; /usr/lib/dyld
0x31933000 - 0x31a78fff  CoreGraphics armv7  &lt;641fb6e558f239588a8bd05dbefff99a&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32350000 - 0x324cefff  Foundation armv7  &lt;ce466f428d953caaac6641d186665809&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x362fd000 - 0x363edfff  QuartzCore armv7  &lt;ff595b1a042933249466e92433e1af6f&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x36d54000 - 0x371edfff  UIKit armv7  &lt;97b527cd6fba35c6bb39263e0f362223&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x378d1000 - 0x3791cfff  CoreLocation armv7  &lt;b640873565a03e45a7d4c38d1b5abade&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
</string>
    <key>displayName</key>
    <string>urbanspin</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>urbanspin</string>
    <key>os_version</key>
    <string>iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)</string>
    <key>system_ID</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>version</key>
    <string>??? (???)</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line: "Application failed to launch on time" seems like the root of the whole thing.  It means the application is doing WAY too much work upon startup in the -applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.  Combine a high loading time with 100% CPU usage, and the app looks like a thrashing bull in a fine china store.  And those are the kinds of apps the OS just loves to kill.

Comment: So, it's really the CPU maxing out and then it's timing out?

Comment: Well, the opening function of every app (-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithoptions).  Needs to exit ASAP.  If it doesn't, a wait_fence is triggered.  20 seconds is way too long, and implies that your app is overloading it's startup function.  The 100% CPU usage was just icing on the cake.

Comment: Makes sense. I just find it odd how every app store application has this problem, I just used UrbanSpoon as an example, but it's all app store apps that have this problem. Both heavy and light on resources applications.

Comment: This seems more like a hardware-specific problem.  I'd direct you to the Genius Bar in your local apple store.  If EVERY app is crashing, it is definitely not the programs themselves.

Comment: According to the thread 0 callstack there are jailbreak libraries  (MobileSubstrate and SubstrateLoader) involved and hacking into the thread. Since you say this is affecting all apps, it is most likely not a hardware issue in general but an issue with those libraries. Remove the jailbreak and those libraries and I wouldn't be surprised if all will run well then.

Comment: Thanks kerni, I would have never caught that